PostgreSQL authentication
I am creating a new database and have found that when I try to view the content tab and have a table selected I get the following error

Loading...Error happen while running pg_dump:
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "" failed: authentication method 10 not supported

Info snapshot
Just learning how to use Postbird with PostgreSQL to create a database with tables
Here are some additional details about my Postbird app

And my postgresql installation


What version of Postgres are you using? Did you switch versions at some point? This error is probably related to password authentication with different encryption types, that can happen when we switch major versions.
